# Undefined en el return de una llamada a Mongo

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb

Tengo este esquema de carrito donde un carrito puede tener un array de productos, a su vez este campo una de sus propiedades es **_id** que referencia al esquema Producto (no lo muestro porque no es necesario pero es lo básico de un producto, codigo, nombre, precio):

```
let carritoSchema = new Schema({
    ...
    productos: [{
        _id: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Producto',
            required: [true, '{PATH} requerido']
        },
        cantidad: {
            type: Number,
            required: [true, '{PATH} requerido'],
            default: 1
        },
        precioVenta: {
            type: Number
        }
    }],
    ...
});
```

Y para agregar un carrito a la base de datos tengo esta función (van a ver que el body viene con cosas como usuario, forma de pago, no las puse en el esquema de arriba porque no son necesarias para lo que me sucede):

```
let addCarrito = (req, res) => {
    let body = req.body;
    let carrito = new Carrito({
        usuario: body.usuario,
        productos: body.productos,
        formaPago: body.formaPago,
        domicilioEntrega: body.domicilioEntrega,
        telefonoEntrega: body.telefonoEntrega,
        informacionEntrega: body.informacionEntrega,
        total: body.total
    });
    carrito.productos.forEach(producto => {
        let id = producto._id;
        const productoObtenido = Producto.findById(id)
        .exec((err, productoDB) => {
            if (err) {
                return false;
            }
            if (!productoDB) {
                return false;
            }
            console.log(productoDB);
            return productoDB;
        });
        console.log(productoObtenido);
    });
    carrito.save((err, carritoDB) => {
        if (err) {
            res.status(400).json({
                ok: false,
                error: err
            })
        }
        res.json({
            ok: true,
            carrito: carritoDB._id
        })
    });
}
```

Lo que quiero hacer, es recorrer el array de productos que me viene, para obtener los productos y de este producto obtener el precioVenta, y guardarlo en la propiedad precioVenta del campo producto del carrito (así, si a futuro el precio del producto cambia, el carrito queda con el precio que se vendio en ese momento el producto). Pero no entiendo bien lo que pasa, soy un poco nuevo en NodeJS y hay algo que no entiendo bien, el `console.log(productoDB);` si me devuelve bien un producto, ej:

```
{
  _id: 5fa00779e8c8633bd00dc9c5,
  precioVenta: 62,
  ...
}
```

Pero el `console.log(productoObtenido);`, me devuelve **undefined**, alguno me dice por que sucede esto y como podría resolverlo?
Gracias.

Comment: Eso te sucede porque cuando usas una función `callback` en el método `exec()` de `Producto.findById()`, entonces se devuelve `undefined`, ya que es un proceso asíncrono. Tu variable `productoDB` sólo existe dentro de esa función `callback` y no podrás sacarla de allí. Lo que debes hacer es ecribir el resto de tu lógica dentro de esa `callback`. Saludos

Comment: Claro, me imagie que era algo así porque me devolvía dos `undefined`, entonces pense que podía llegar a ser por eso. Nunca hice algo así como me decís, de escribir la lógica dentro del `callback`, me podrías dar un ejemplo? Gracias por la respuesta!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**PROBLEMA**

El problema (siempre lo es) es de asincronía. Todo proceso de lectura / escritura en base de datos es un proceso asíncrono, por lo tanto, los datos devueltos por la consulta no estarán disponibles inmediatamente al llamar al método de la consulta, sino que serán pasados como argumento a la función `callback` que utilicemos para procesarlos.

Esto quiere decir que, dada la naturaleza de Javascript, al llamar al método `findById(id).exec(callback)`, el mismo no devolverá un resultado, sino que ejecutará la siguiente instrucción en el orden que aparezca, la cual en este caso es un `console.log(productoObtenido)`. Y dado que el mismo es `undefined` eso es lo que muestra en consola.

Por otro lado, estás intentando hacer una serie de operaciones con elementos de una lista, lo cual si bien parece lo correcto, dada la naturaleza de la información, no es lo adecuado.

Actualmente tienes:

```js
carrito.productos.forEach(producto => {
  let id = producto._id;
  const productoObtenido = Producto.findById(id)
  .exec((err, productoDB) => {
      if (err) {
        return false;
      }
      if (!productoDB) {
        return false;
      }
      console.log(productoDB);
      return productoDB;
  });
  console.log(productoObtenido);
});
```

Lo cual no es muy eficiente desde el punto de vista de la cantidad de consultas que se realizan a la BD. Si tienes 100 productos, haces 100 peticiones para obtener los productos, cosa que podrías lograr con **¡¡una sola consulta!!**.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Una de las soluciones es escribir el resto de tu lógica dentro de la función `callback`, es lo que haré en mi respuesta, además te mostraré la forma de realizar una sola consulta sin importar la cantidad de elementos que estemos consultando.

Lo primero será realizar la consulta, la cual puedes hacer así:

```js
let addCarrito = (req, res) => {
  let carrito = new Carrito(req.body); // <- no necesitas escribir los valores, luego lo explico
  //obtenemos la lista de ids de cada producto
  let productosId = carrito.productos.map(producto => producto._id);
  Producto.find({_id: {$in: productosId}}).exec((error, productos) => { ... });
  // ...
```

Como puedes observar he realizado algunos cambios de cara a mejorar la cantidad de código innecesario que escribes.

Cuando creas una instancia de un Modelo de Mongoose, no importa si el objeto del que sacas la información tiene más o menos campos que el modelo, se llenarán todos los que contenga el objeto origen y los que no existan serán `undefined` y los que sobren no se tomarán en cuenta. Eso te ahorra escribir cada campo de `req.body` al crear la instancia del modelo y se resume en un simple: `new Carrito(req.body);`

Por otro lado, puedes obtener una lista de todos los productos de la colección de productos que coincidan con los `_id` que están en la lista creada (`productosId`). Puedes ver la notación usada al llamar al método `map()` del tipo `Array`. Se le conoce como programación funcional.

Para consultar en una sola llamada por todos los productos, usamos el operador de consulta [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/index.html) de MongoDB, que como se observa recibe una lista y busca todos los elementos de la colección que tengan un campo `_id` coincidente con algún valor de la lista.

Si se consigue algún documento se añadirá a la lista de resultados, si no se consigue ningún elemento, la lista será devuelta vacía.

Ahora que tenemos la lista de productos, podemos proceder a salvar el carrito con los productos de la lista, o devolver un mensaje al cliente indicando que ocurrió un error o que la lista de productos está vacía (no se encontraron coincidencias). Este proceso debe hacerse dentro de la función `callback` que devuelve los resultados de esta primera consulta:

```js
let addCarrito = (req, res) => {
  let carrito = new Carrito(req.body);
  let productosId = carrito.productos.map(producto => producto._id);
  Producto.find({_id: {$in: productosId}}, (error, productos) => {
    if(error) {
      return res.status(500).json({
        message: 'Ocurrió un error'
      });
    }
    if(!productos.length) {
      return res.status(404).json({
        message: 'No se encontró ningún producto'
      });
    }
    let cantidadProductosOriginal = carrito.productos.length;
    carrito.productos = [ ...productos]; // <- reemplazamos los productos del carrito por la lista de productos existente obtenida
    carrito.save((error, saved) => {
      if (error) {
        return res.status(500).json({
          ok: false,
          error: 'Ocurrió un error' // nunca muestres el error interno
        });
      }
      return res.json({
        ok: true,
        carrito: saved._id,
        productosSalvados: productos.length,
        productosOriginales: cantidadProductosOriginal
      });
    }); // finaliza carrito.save
  }); // finaliza Producto.find
} // finaliza addCarrito
```

Una de las cosas importantes que debes notar es que cada vez que llamo al método de respuesta al cliente (`res`), lo hago usando la sentencia `return`. Esto es porque de esa forma doy por finalizado el proceso de la función y la misma ya no se ejecutará a partir de ese punto. Esto nos evitará los errores de tipo `Cannot set headers before they are send`, que son tan comunes porque se olvida este pequeño detalle.

También es bueno tomar en cuenta que nunca se debe enviar el mensaje de error interno del servidor al cliente. Si MongoDB nos devuelve un error, es para nosotros y no para el cliente.

Por último, puedes ver que agregué 2 valores a la respuesta cuando el carrito ha sido salvado, esto con la idea de informar cuantos productos, de los enviados originalmente, fueron salvados efectivamente en el carrito.

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.

Comment: Wow, no solo me solucionaste el problema, sino que me diste la mejor explicación que pude encontrar en Internet. Me sacaste varias dudas que tengo ya que soy nuevo en JS. Muchisimas gracias, increible respuesta ojala tengas muchos +1.

Comment: Mientras mas leo el código mas me gusta. La parte de reemplazar los productos del carrito por la lista obtenida es genial, yo buscaba reemplazar únicamente la propiedad precioVenta, pero usando el operador `...` es mucho mejor. El paso de C# a esto se me dificulta pero JS tiene muy buenas cosas. Genial tu ayuda!